# SqLite Update Error

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert, sql-update

I would like to know what is wrong with this code.
I get the problem: error near "," syntax error

It accepts an item code and a item object.

```
public override int Update(string ItemCode, Item Item)
{
    int rc = 0;

    try
    {
        _sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(_connStr);
        _sqlConnection.Open();
```

I think the problem lies with the next statement:

```
        string updateQuery = string.Format("UPDATE ItemDatabase SET _itemDescription=@ItemDescription, _ItemPrice=@ItemPrice, _ItemName=@ItemName WHERE [_itemDescription] = '{0}' AND [_itemPrice] = '{1}' AND [_itemName] = '{2}'", Item.ItemDescription, Item.ItemPrice, Item.ItemName);
```

Im not sure if it should be seperated by commas.

```
        SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(updateQuery, _sqlConnection);

        SQLiteParameter[] sqlParams = new SQLiteParameter[]
            {
            new SQLiteParameter("@ItemDescription",DbType.String),
            new SQLiteParameter("@ItemPrice",DbType.String),
            new SQLiteParameter("@ItemName", DbType.String)
            }; // end SQLiteParameter
        sqlParams[0].Value = Item.ItemDescription;
        sqlParams[1].Value = Item.ItemPrice;
        sqlParams[2].Value = Item.ItemName;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
        rc = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rc == 1)
        {
            rc = 0;
        }
        _sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: What you see as `updateQuery` when you debug your code?

Comment: Why do you put that underscore in front of your fields?

Comment: And something is not quite right here. The values used for the parameters are the same values used for the query. So you don't find anything or you update the field to the same value

Comment: In the table My field names are named with underscores. I have put in "and" into they code and removed the commas, then it gives me this message: Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Comment: I changed the code now, it says item updated but the data haven't changed

Comment: I have edited the code above to the new code I have in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update query is the following.

```
string updateQuery = string.Format(@"UPDATE ItemDatabase 
      SET _itemDescription=@ItemDescription, 
      _ItemPrice=@ItemPrice, 
      _ItemName=@ItemName 
      WHERE [_itemDescription] = '{0}', 
            [_itemPrice] = '{1}', 
            [_itemName] = '{2}'", Item.ItemDescription, Item.ItemPrice, Item.ItemName);
```

so your parameters should be called

```
   SQLiteParameter[] sqlParams = new SQLiteParameter[]
   {
        new SQLiteParameter("@ItemDescription",DbType.String),
        new SQLiteParameter("@ItemPrice",DbType.String),
        new SQLiteParameter("@ItemName", DbType.String)
    };
```

Of course the correct syntax for the WHERE statement requires that when you have multiple conditions you join them with AND or OR operators

```
      WHERE [_itemDescription] = '{0}' AND 
            [_itemPrice] = '{1}' AND 
            [_itemName] = '{2}'", Item.ItemDescription, Item.ItemPrice, Item.ItemName);
```

But again, as I have asked in the comment above, you are using the same values for the parameters collection and for the where clause. If you use the same values no change will ever be applied to the database.

Let me give an example:

```
  Item.Description = "Item1";
  Item.ItemPrice = "100";
  Item.ItemName = "Stuff";
```

Your query becomes:

```
string updateQuery = @"UPDATE ItemDatabase 
      SET _itemDescription='Item1', 
      _ItemPrice='100', 
      _ItemName='Stuff' 
      WHERE [_itemDescription] = 'Item1' AND 
            [_itemPrice] = '100' AND 
            [_itemName] = 'Stuff'");
```

So no change to your data even if a record is found

Comment: I changed the paramaters from "@_itemDescription" to "@ItemDescription" and "@_itemPrice" to "@ItemPrice" and "@_itemName" to "@ItemName", is that what you ment by the values are the same

Answer (score 0):

`where condition, condition, condition` is not valid SQL. You either meant `where condition and condition and condition` or `where condition or condition or condition`.

Also, you can get rid of those `catch` blocks which are doing nothing but resetting the exception stack trace.